# Annotations in datanucleus

Tags: annotations, datanucleus, persistent

I'm trying insert on a view using datanucleus, the problem is, when i put @Persistent in field that has no corresponding field in table and i catch the error:

11:03:42,782 INFO  [br.com.sigel.server.censo.dao.persistentDAO.ParametrosCensoDAO] - javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown flushing changes to datastore
NestedThrowables:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here

but when i put @NotPersistent, don't get fields from view and fields stay empty.
I need these fields are completed according to the view, but never overwritten (read-only).

My code is:

```
    @PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION,detachable="true", table="VW_FILA_CENSO") 
    @Sequence(datastoreSequence = "SEQ_SG_FICE_SEQ", strategy = SequenceStrategy.CONTIGUOUS, name = "seqFice")
    @Cacheable("false")
    public class SG_Fila_Censo implements BeanModelTag,Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@NotPersistent 
private Integer escoSeq;
@Persistent(primaryKey="true", valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.SEQUENCE, sequence="seqFice")
    private Integer fice_seq;

@Persistent
private Date fice_data_solicitacao; 

@Persistent
private Boolean fice_processando;

@Persistent
private Boolean fice_priorizado;

@Persistent
private Integer fice_rece_seq;

@Persistent
private Integer fice_colb_seq;

@Persistent
private String unidade_escolar;

@Persistent
private String nome_colaborador;

@Persistent
private Integer etapa_relatorio;

@Persistent
private String cree_cod;
```

...

My view is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "SCH_SECULT3"."VW_FILA_CENSO"
(FICE_SEQ,FICE_DATA_SOLICITACAO,FICE_PROCESSANDO,FICE_PRIORIZADO,FICE_RECE_SEQ,FICE_COLB_SEQ,unidade_escolar,nome_colaborador,cree_cod,etapa_relatorio)
AS
(SELECT
    SG_FILA_CENSO.FICE_SEQ,
    SG_FILA_CENSO.FICE_DATA_SOLICITACAO,
    SG_FILA_CENSO.FICE_PROCESSANDO,
    SG_FILA_CENSO.FICE_PRIORIZADO,
    SG_FILA_CENSO.FICE_RECE_SEQ,
    SG_FILA_CENSO.FICE_COLB_SEQ,
    VW_RELATORIO_CENSO.unidade_escolar,
    VW_RELATORIO_CENSO.nome_colaborador,
    VW_RELATORIO_CENSO.cree_cod,
    VW_RELATORIO_CENSO.rece_etapa
    FROM SG_FILA_CENSO,VW_RELATORIO_CENSO
    where SG_FILA_CENSO.fice_rece_seq = VW_RELATORIO_CENSO.rece_seq
);
```

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't use JDO for write operations on a view (even though the DB might support it). You can however use a DataNucleus extension (so its not part of the JDO specification) for read purposes on a view. This [Documentenion](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/rdbms/views.html) of DataNucleus show you how you can use the views for readonly purposes.

The '@NotPersisted' annotation tells DataNucleus it should leave the field alone so its only logical it does not populate it with data from the DB.

I also noticed some other things in your code example; Why aren't you using primitives for booleans and integers ? Their Object counter parts (which you are using) are generally only used for use in Generic collections and if you really need 'null' as a value. Autoboxing ensures that you don't see the difference. Primatives are faster and don't use as much memory and therefor it is common practice to use those instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can put @Column(insertable = false) annotation (e.g. @Column(name = "SOURCE_DESC", length = 512, insertable = false) - calculated DB view attribute). This tells persistance unit not to insert this column value to DB table. But still, value will be queried while retrieving data from DB view.

Gediminas